# Fields of history object

Tags: visualforce, field-history

Can someone list the fields in history object? Since I wanted them to display in a page block in vf page despite using history related list.

Comment: Do you want to create custom history object to store the audit history of the object?

Answer (score 0):

There is no History object. In fact many standard object has something you have on your mind, but they usually have unique names, for example CaseHistory, LeadHistory, etc.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casehistory.htm
In this link you will find name of CaseHistory fields. In VisualForce you use them same as other objects. If you like to know 'history' object, most of the time you need to add to standard object name 'History', but not every object has it. 
However if you like to declare it you have to use SOQL query.